# Trying to upload images to my AWS S3 bucket using AWS-shell

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

The following is my python script to upload the code.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

# Get list of objects for indexing
images=[('Micheal_Jordan.jpg','Micheal Jordan'),
      ('Wayne_Rooney.jpg','Wayne Rooney')
      ]

# Iterate through list to upload objects to S3
for image in images:
    file = open(image[0],'rb')
    object = s3.Object('famouspersons-images','index/'+ image[0])
    ret = object.put(Body=file,
                    Metadata={'FullName':image[1]})
```

Getting the following error.

```
botocore.exceptions.SSLError: SSL validation failed for https://s3bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/index/Wayne_Rooney.jpg [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)
```

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs because Python SSL library can't find certificates on your local machine to verify against.

You can check if you have your `ca_bundle` set to something else:

```
python -c "from botocore.session import Session; print(Session().get_config_variable('ca_bundle'))"
```

If it doesn't print anything, then it uses default path. You can check default path by:

```
python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.get_default_verify_paths())"
```

If something is printed on the screen, then it was set by `AWS_CA_BUNDLE` environment variable or by `aws configure set default.ca_bundle <some path>` in the past.

You can install certificates by following
`https://gist.github.com/marschhuynh/31c9375fc34a3e20c2d3b9eb8131d8f3`.
Then you can save it as `install-cert.py` and run then run `python install-cert.py`.

If this does not work out, you can try the following solutions:

- [Reset AWS Credentials using AWS Configure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54773707/11758843)
- [Issue Due to Fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40517581/11758843)
- [Reset HTTP/HTTPS Proxy Related Environment Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48874444/11758843)
- [Reinstall and Upgrade AWS CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53746691/11758843)
- [Using AWS_CA_BUNDLE Environment Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55117069/11758843)
- [Moving CA Certificate PEM File in the Right Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62939329/11758843)
- [Verifying CA Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27847883/11758843)
- [Install certifi Python Module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48134650/11758843)
- [Install pyopenssl Python Module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48810442/11758843)
- [Adding Trusted Root CA Details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52051009/11758843)
- [Adding Trusted Host](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44390144/11758843)
- [Fixing the Version of requests and urllib3 Python Modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55996714/11758843)
- [Fixing CA Certificate Content and Location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31915123/11758843)